# How do I dynamically create a new dataframe from iterating over multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, for-loop

New to python.

I have this data:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
       'Date': np.random.choice(pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', 
        freq='D', periods=180)), 6),
       'Period': np.random.uniform(50, 200, 6),
      }, columns=['CustomerID', 'Date', 'Period'])
sample
```

I want to add the `'Period'` column to the `'Date'` column, recording each new date in a separate dataframe with columns of the `CustomerID` and `New Date`. However, I want to record each new date (iterating over the previous new date) until the new date > 2020.

I made a function:

```
def proj(ids=None):
end = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') 
for x in ids:
    date = projection.loc[projection['CustomerID'] == x, 'Date'] 
    period = projection.loc[projection['CustomerID'] == x, 'Period'])
    time_left = end - date  
    ratio = float(round(time_left.dt.days / period)) # how many times the period fits in time_left
    itera = np.arange(1, ratio, 1) 
    for i in itera:
        deltas = [i * period]
        df = pd.Series(deltas).map(float).map(dt.timedelta) 
        pdates = pd.Series((date + df)) 
        pdates = pdates.map(pd.to_datetime)
        print(dates)
```

Not only have I obviously not figured out how to create a new dataframe for my output, but this function also only works for one of my CustomerIDs and no others.

I'm really stuck on what I can do next.

Thanks for your help.

edit: For reference, I want the output to look like

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
                  'New Date': ['2018-09-28', '2019-01-21', '2019-05-16','2019-09-08',
                              '2018-09-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-07-31']})
output
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output?

Comment: `output = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
                      'New Date': ['2018-09-28', '2019-01-21', '2019-05-16','2019-09-08',
                                  '2018-09-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-07-31']})`
 `output`

Comment: Do you care about the decimal component of Period or would shifting by the rounded number of days suffice?  Both are possible, but the rounded is a little cleaner.

Comment: Ideally we would be as accurate as possible, but that's fine in reality.

Comment: But in your output example there is no date > 2020...??

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I only want dates up to 2020, none at or after. @SpghttCd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `sample` as below:

```
  CustomerID       Date  Period
0          1 2018-01-16     152
1          2 2018-06-28     109
2          3 2018-03-07      59
3          4 2018-03-30     172
4          5 2018-01-07      92
5          6 2018-05-22     164
```

First, let's specify an end date convert `Date` to `datetime` objects.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
end_date = datetime.strptime('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
sample['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['Date'])
```

Now, for each row, let's create a list of dates.

```
sample['dates'] = sample.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['Date'], end=end_date, freq='D')[::x['Period']], axis=1)
```

Simply flatten the dates, keeping the `CustomerID`

```
output = sample[['CustomerID', 'dates']].set_index('CustomerID')['dates'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(name='New Date').drop('level_1',1)
```

Output:

```
   CustomerID   New Date
0           1 2018-01-16
1           1 2018-06-17
2           1 2018-11-16
3           1 2019-04-17
4           1 2019-09-16
5           2 2018-06-28
6           2 2018-10-15
7           2 2019-02-01
8           2 2019-05-21
9           2 2019-09-07
10          2 2019-12-25
11          3 2018-03-07
12          3 2018-05-05
13          3 2018-07-03
14          3 2018-08-31
15          3 2018-10-29
16          3 2018-12-27
17          3 2019-02-24
18          3 2019-04-24
19          3 2019-06-22
20          3 2019-08-20
21          3 2019-10-18
22          3 2019-12-16
23          4 2018-03-30
24          4 2018-09-18
25          4 2019-03-09
26          4 2019-08-28
27          5 2018-01-07
28          5 2018-04-09
29          5 2018-07-10
30          5 2018-10-10
31          5 2019-01-10
32          5 2019-04-12
33          5 2019-07-13
34          5 2019-10-13
35          6 2018-05-22
36          6 2018-11-02
37          6 2019-04-15
38          6 2019-09-26
```

Comment: That only outputs the first iteration of the period + the date. I need every iteration until the new date is after 2020.

Comment: It's generally better to create a list dynamically and a data frame from the list. pandas does not handle what you want to do very well. why a dataframe in the first place?

Comment: @Chad, see the edit. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: @HarvIpan that looks great, except I'm getting `ValueError: ('n argument must be an integer, got 84.97301157674099', 'occurred at index 0')` on the `sample['dates']` line

Comment: @Chad, you have to convert your periods to `int`, see my input dataframe. It is because `pandas.date_range` expects `periods` to be `int`